# How to handle live messaging in Mean stack application?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean

I'm planning to develop a MEAN Stack application. After searching internet i'm not getting myself so clear on how to handle live messaging in my application which would just work like whatsapp/fb messenger or any other chat applications.

Initially i thought of using setTimeout function and make a REST call for latest data on some specified no.of seconds, but i don't know whether it's a feasible option.

Can anyone help me to understand what would be the best practice to update messages on both server and client sides?

Comment: Have you seen anything about websockets ? Seems more natural.

Comment: Can i use it in MEAN app?

Comment: why not? [socket.io](https://socket.io)

Comment: Node should be able to handle websockets. Angular does for sure.

Comment: @Random Could you please elaborate a bit how Angular does this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Socket.io. It is a websocket which allows you to communicate between browser and server. It's very easy to setup and start using.

You can install it with `npm install --save socket.io` (assuming you installed express already 'cause you want a MEAN app)

Then you can start with basics like this:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
   console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

You can find the documentations in [here](https://socket.io/)
Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm in this exact situation (chat with a MEAN app). I've managed to do a couple of things, but I have no idea how to set everything with mongodb (in order to save the messages). Also, I managed to send messages from one tab to another, but I am not very sure on how to do it regarding different real users.